# ReactJS: State is not working inside nested function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

So I tried to modify the tagList using setTagList(). It changed the content of the page (it adds tags in the <Filter /> component) but I cannot implement that each tag in <Filter /> is unique.

```
import Filter from "./components/Filter";
import Card from "./components/Card";
import data from "./assets/data.json";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"


export default function App() { 
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [tagList, setTagList] = useState([]);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    generateCards();
  }, []);

  function addTag(newTag) {
    // console.log(tagList) always outputs []

    if (!tagList.includes(newTag)) {
      setTagList(oldTagList => [...oldTagList, newTag])
      // console.log(tagList) here always outputs []
      // But if I change "const [tagList, setTagList] = useState([]);" to "let [tagList, setTagList] = useState([]);" and add "tagList = [...tagList, newTag]" here, it works
    }  
  }  

  function deleteTag(tag) {
    setTagList((oldTags) => oldTags.filter((oldTag) => oldTag !== tag));
  }

  function clearTags() {
    setTagList([]);
  }

  function generateCards() {
    setCards(
      data.map((cardData) => (
        <Card
          key={cardData.id}
          logo={cardData.logo}
          company={cardData.company}
          isNew={cardData.new}
          isFeatured={cardData.featured}
          position={cardData.position}
          postedAt={cardData.postedAt}
          contract={cardData.contract}
          location={cardData.location}
          tags={[
            cardData.role,
            cardData.level,
            ...cardData.languages,
            ...cardData.tools,
          ]}
          addTag={addTag}
          filter={filter}
        />
      ))
    );
  }

  // console.log(tagList) works normally

  return (
    <div className="bg-bg-color h-screen">
      <div className="relative bg-wave-pattern w-full h-28 text-bg-color bg-primary">
        {tagList.length !== 0 && (
          <Filter tagList={tagList} deleteTag={deleteTag} clearTags={clearTags} />
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="2xl:px-96 xl:px-64 lg:px-32 md:px-16 sm:px-4 py-16 space-y-8">{cards}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to console.log(tagList) in the addTag() function but it always returns the default value. But when console.log(tagList) outside the function, it works like normal.
But when I changed the const keyword to let when setting the state and add "tagList = [...tagList, newTag]" right after setTagList(...), it works.
Is React broken?

Comment: Don't store UI in state. Store *data*, and then *render it in UI*. Just call `setCards(data)` in your `useEffect` and move the mapping to your render return value: `return cards.map((cardData) => ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `generateCards` function is only called from the `useEffect` above, which has no dependencies, meaning it's only called when the component is mounted.

This means that the `addTag` callback prop from the `Card` component always references the same `addTag` function that was created on component mount, so its closure only sees the initial `tagList` value (`[]`).

One quick fix might be to add `tagList` as dependency to the `useEffect` that calls `generateCards`, so that all cards are re-rendered every time `tagList` changes, making the newly rendered cards reference the most recent `addTag` function that also has the most recent `tagList` value in its context:

```js
const data = ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2', 'Tag 3', 'Tag 4']

function App() { 
  const [cards, setCards] = React.useState([]);
  const [tagList, setTagList] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    generateCards();
  }, [tagList]); // <= ONLY CHANGED THIS LINE

  function addTag(e) {
    const newTag = e.currentTarget.textContent;

    if (!tagList.includes(newTag)) {
      setTagList(oldTagList => [...oldTagList, newTag])
    }  
  }  

  function deleteTag(e) {
    const tag = e.currentTarget.textContent;
    
    setTagList((oldTags) => oldTags.filter((oldTag) => oldTag !== tag));
  }

  function clearTags() {
    setTagList([]);
  }

  function generateCards() {    
    setCards(
      data.map((tag) => {
        const isSelected = tagList.includes(tag);
        
        return (
          <button
            key={tag}
            onClick={ isSelected ? deleteTag : addTag }
            className={ `card${ isSelected ? ' selected' : '' }` }>
            { tag }
          </button>
        )
      })
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {cards}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
body,
button {
  font-family: monospace;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.card + .card {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.card.selected {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

However, I would advise you to use [`useMemo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) rather than storing JSX in the state, as well as updating your `addTag` function to check if a tag is included in the currently selected ones that come from the previous state, rather than using the `tagList` from the function's context:

```js
const data = ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2', 'Tag 3', 'Tag 4']

function App() { 
  const [tagList, setTagList] = React.useState([]);

  function addTag(e) {
    const tag = e.currentTarget.textContent;

    // CHANGED THIS:
    setTagList((oldTags) => oldTags.includes(tag) ? oldTags : [...oldTags, tag])
  }  

  function deleteTag(e) {
    const tag = e.currentTarget.textContent;
    
    setTagList((oldTags) => oldTags.filter((oldTag) => oldTag !== tag));
  }

  function clearTags() {
    setTagList([]);
  }
    
  // CHANGED THIS:
  const memoizedCards = React.useMemo(() => {
    return data.map((tag) => {
      const isSelected = tagList.includes(tag);

      return (
        <button
          key={tag}
          onClick={ isSelected ? deleteTag : addTag }
          className={ `card${ isSelected ? ' selected' : '' }` }>
          { tag }
        </button>
      )
    })
  }, [tagList])

  return (
    <div>
      {memoizedCards}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
body,
button {
  font-family: monospace;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.card + .card {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.card.selected {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I'm very grateful of your help. It is indeed the dependencies problem that causes this bug. If you weren't here I would take another 4 hours to fix this.

Comment: You should then mark this as the accepted answer, if it resolved your issue.

Comment: Oops my bad. I thought I checked your answer

Comment: Oh I cannot check 2 answers at once, that's why yours got unchecked

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you only update the value of `cards` (using `setCards`) one time—right after the component mounts. This is because you only call `generateCards` within a `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array so it only runs the first time the component renders. Since the value of `cards` is the one from the first render, the `addTag` function given to each card is the initial value of `addTag`, which references the initial value of `tagList` (an empty array).

While you can fix this by adding `tagList` to the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook, a more straightforward way to handle this would be to put the conditional logic of `addTag` within the callback passed to `setTagList`, like this:

```
function addTag(newTag) {
  setTagList(oldTagList => !oldTagList.includes(newTag) ? [...oldTagList, newTag] : oldTagList);
}
```

Additionally, there is no need to store `cards` in state, and doing so can introduce problems such as the one you have encountered here. If you need to optimize performance, you should use `useMemo`, but I would start out just rendering the cards directly in the `return` statement, like this:

```
export default function App() { 
  const [tagList, setTagList] = useState([]);

  function addTag(newTag) {
    setTagList(oldTagList => !oldTagList.includes(newTag) ? [...oldTagList, newTag] : oldTagList)
  }  

  function deleteTag(tag) {
    setTagList((oldTags) => oldTags.filter((oldTag) => oldTag !== tag));
  }

  function clearTags() {
    setTagList([]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="bg-bg-color h-screen">
      <div className="relative bg-wave-pattern w-full h-28 text-bg-color bg-primary">
        {tagList.length !== 0 && (
          <Filter tagList={tagList} deleteTag={deleteTag} clearTags={clearTags} />
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="2xl:px-96 xl:px-64 lg:px-32 md:px-16 sm:px-4 py-16 space-y-8">
        {data.map((cardData) => (
          <Card
            key={cardData.id}
            logo={cardData.logo}
            company={cardData.company}
            isNew={cardData.new}
            isFeatured={cardData.featured}
            position={cardData.position}
            postedAt={cardData.postedAt}
            contract={cardData.contract}
            location={cardData.location}
            tags={[
              cardData.role,
              cardData.level,
              ...cardData.languages,
              ...cardData.tools,
            ]}
            addTag={addTag}
            filter={filter}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. By the way is storing JSX in state bad practice? Does it affect performance or something like that?

Comment: I consider it bad practice but there are always exceptions. It's not about JSX specifically and not about performance, it's that you're storing dependent information in state, which you shouldn't do. Instead you could use `useMemo`. As a simple example, you wouldn't store the number of cards (from `data.length`) in state because it can become outdated, instead you would either put that in `useMemo` (if expensive) or just compute directly within the component body.